# Fetching WordPress.org reviews via API

Tags: wordpress, api, plugins, review

I want to fetch a plugin review from wordpress.org via API, is it possible? I tried using [https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/{slug}.json](https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/%7Bslug%7D.json) but no luck? Is there anyone available for help?

Answer (score -1):

To fetch reviews of a WordPress plugin from the WordPress plugin directory, you can use the WordPress.org Plugin API. The API allows you to retrieve information about a plugin, including its reviews, by sending a GET request to a specific endpoint.

Here's an example of how you can use the API to retrieve reviews for a plugin with the slug "akismet":

`https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/?action=plugin_information&request[slug]=akismet`

This will return JSON data containing information about the plugin, including an array of reviews. You can then parse the JSON data and extract the reviews as needed. At this moment it only returns 10 reviews.

Comment: What does that mean? I did not get any review by the client, check the [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/26uhc98). I need the client's name and their reviews, can you please help?

Comment: That’s the stats of total stars per release. Not reviews.